# Any way to override bean definition for spring data jpa repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

We have a sample app that showcases some things we are doing client side. It pulls in a few internal libraries to get everything functional. It dummies in some hard-coded data so it doesn't have to be concerned with any kind of persistence mechanism.

In some of these libraries that are pulled in, there are spring data jpa repositories. Something like this:

```
public interface MyLibraryEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyLibraryEntity, Long>
{
   //...
}
```

When the server starts up, I get an error like this:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myLibraryEntityRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#788f64f1' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#788f64f1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
```

It can't find the `entityManager`, but I don't *want* to have to use an `entityManager`. So, in an attempt to override the `myLibraryEntityRepository` bean, I added the following to my Java config:

```
@Bean
public MyLibraryEntityRepository getMyLibraryEntityRepository()
{
    return myDummyImpl();
}
```

However, this results in the same error.

Is there any way I can override the bean definition for the spring data jpa repository so that I can use my own dummy implementation and not have to configure an `entityManager` in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Bean(name="dummyBean") and the in the @Autowired use the annotation @Qualifier("dummyBean")

Comment: The problem with this is that there are beans in the libraries wiring it in, and I can't add the `@Qualifier` to the library code. I could override the beans using the repository, but I don't want to have to maintain which services are using the repository. I just want to override the repository and be done.